# Is there any way I can get Altium to calculate a correct via delay?

Tags: altium, delay, high-speed, via

Via delay is different between layers, it's also different between the top and bottom layers and say top and an inner layer. Altium only provides one delay for each via, which means if you switched layers, you would have to change the via delay. As far as I know alitum only provides a fixed delay.

Is there any way for altium to calculate a variable delay of a via, or automatically calculate it?

[image]

Comment: I've not dealt with via delay calculations (yet) but I did find that Altium has a video on the topic: https://youtu.be/6AQb86SwxbY -- it seems you have to calculate it first then include it. So the short answer, I think, is, "no."

Comment: Yeah I watched that video before posting, it didn't explain how to take care of via delay that varies with layer